# Flux across the surface $x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} = 1$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $S$ be the oriented surface $x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} =1$ with the unit normal $\hat{n}$ pointing outward for the vector field $F = xi +yj+ zk$, the value of double integration of $\vec{F} . \hat{n} dS$ is -

We need to evaluate flux across the given surface, which can easily be done by gauss divergence formula and it comes out to be $4\pi$.

I am trying to solve this by below method-

$\int \int \vec{F} . \hat{n} dS$
$$= \int \int \vec{F} . \frac{grad S}{ | grad S| } \frac{|grad S|}{|grad S. \hat{p}|} dA$$ ( this integration is over R which is shadow region of surface S, $\hat{p}$ is the unit normal vector to R)
So, flux = $$\int \int \frac{F.grad S}{|grad S. \hat{p}|} dA$$

$$= \int\int \frac{(xi + yj + zk).(2xi +2yj+2zk)dxdy}{|2z. \hat{k}|}$$

$$= \int\int \frac{2x^{2} + 2y^{2} + 2z^{2}}{2z} dxdy$$

$$= \int \int (1/z) dxdy$$
$$= \int \int 1/(1 - x^{2} -y^{2})^{1/2}dxdy
$$

further, this integration leads to $2\pi$ which is wrong. So, where did I go wrong?

Comment: It's not wrong. $2\pi$ is the flux over the upper half of the sphere. $4\pi$ is the entire sphere.

Comment: @Dylan why does the above integration find the flux over the upper half sphere only?

Comment: Both the upper and the lower half have the same projection on the $\Bbb R^2$ plane. So the projection integral is equivalent to only one half of the sphere

Comment: It's a little inconvenient to answer when you leave out the bounds of the integration when that's exactly what you're confused about.  Probably putting them in would resolve your own confusion.

Comment: @Mathsaddict Why did you put a modulus around $\vec{\nabla S}\cdot\hat p$?

Comment: @Shubham johri since dA is the projection of dS in region R, so, $dA = dS |cos\theta|$ where $\theta$ is angle between $dA$ and $dS$. Mod is appiied because area cannot be negative. Then $$dS = \frac{dA}{|cos\theta|} = \frac{|grad f|}{|grad S.\hat{p}|}dA$$

Comment: By putting a modulus there, you are ignoring the fact that $\hat p=-\hat k$ for the lower hemisphere. Also, $z=-(1-x^2-y^2)^{1/2}$ for the lower hemisphere. To resolve this, you should break your original integral into two integrals: one for the upper and the other for the lower hemisphere

Comment: $\hat{p}$ can be $\hat{k}$ or $-\hat{k}$. So, I need to calculate flux for both and then adding both flux will give the complete solution. Right? If I am missing something, then please add it to your answer. It would be really helpful.

Comment: The flux for the bottom half should be equal to the top half, since the two negative signs cancel each other out. Also, it is true that $dS$ is positive, but $\hat{\mathbf{n}}dS$ *can* be negative since orientation matters, therefore $$ \hat{\mathbf{n}}dS = \frac{\nabla S}{\nabla S \cdot \mathbf{p}} dA $$ and the absolute value should not be there in the final integral.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\vec F=x\hat i+y\hat j+z\hat k=\vec r,\hat n=\hat r\ \therefore\vec F\cdot\vec r=r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}=1$

$dS=rd\theta\cdot r\sin\theta\ d\phi=r^2\sin\theta\ d\theta\ d\phi=\sin\theta\ d\theta\ d\phi$

$\displaystyle\therefore\int\int\vec F\cdot\hat n\ dS=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\sin\theta\ d\theta\ d\phi=4\pi$.

As for your method, the flux through the upper half is $2\pi$. Add to that the $2\pi$ of the lower half.